# The number of functions in C library

Tags: c, gcc, gnu, glibc

I want to know there are how many functions I can call in C library, e.g. Gnu C library? or Approximately?

Comment: Read the library documentation? :)

Comment: there are many many function in libc (the gnu c library)  here is a link to a list (caveat: this list changes with each new release of the library:  <http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Function-Index.html>  However, it should be noted that there are a bunch of libraries used by 'c' besides the libc library

Comment: You should clarify what you want. There are functions required by the standard for *hosted* and for *freestanding* environments and they also depend on the version of the standard. And then there are implementations (such as GNU C) coming with quite some non-standard extensions. Which count are you interested in?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are in unix like OS, you can use `nm` utility, part of [gnu binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/). In my cygwin environment, `nm` lists 1570 symbols defined in the text section.

```
% nm -C /usr/lib/libc.a  | grep -w T | wc -l
1570
```

Let's exclude the `_` variants

```
% nm -C /usr/lib/libc.a  | grep -w T | grep -v _ | wc -l
751
```

If you are on windows, try [dumpbin](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/177429) utility.

```
% dumpbin /exports msvcr110.dll
```

`-C` in the `nm` command demangles the symbol names. I do not know how to get `dumpbin` to print original symbol names. If anyone knows how to, please suggest.

Some functions might be defined in another object file - like libm for math, libnsl for network services etc. To be sure, also look at the library documentation/source.

Comment: Nice answer, but a little nitpick: there *are* functions part of a standard C library that are implemented in a different library (e.g. all maths functions in `libm` with GNU C, not sure whether this is standard) ... just not sure what exactly the OP is interested in.

Comment: @FelixPalmen In cygwin, libc.a appears to define pow, sin etc. `nm -C /usr/lib/libc.a | grep -P 'pow|sin'`. As you said, it could be implementation specific.

Comment: @FelixPalmen I just checked in ubuntu. Math functions are not defined in libc.a. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I know ;) But didn't check *cygwin* myself. Just commented because the question is somewhat vague, probably because OP doesn't know about issues like that.